# Execute code in node.js from a child process

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

new to node.js I'm trying to execute some code in a child process from a module.

Let me explain, I have my simple server in index.js

```
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

server.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
});
```

When a url is fetched I launch a child process :

```
function handleRequest(req, res){  
    console.log('Request path = ' + req.url)
    launchWorker(req.url)
    res.end('Path Hit: ' + req.url);
}

// workers execution 
function launchWorker(path) {
    const worker = child_process.spawn('node', ['./worker.js', path.substring(1)])

    worker.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('worker: ' + data.toString())
    }); 

    worker.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('stderr : ' + data)
    }); 

    worker.on('close', function(code, signal) {
        console.log('child process exited with code: ' + code)
    }); 
}
```

So I have a worker.js file that execute some code, I managed to pass some data from my server to my child process, using `['./worker.js', path.substring(1)]`

I use firebase to perform some operations, so in my worker.js I initialise my firebase admin, credentials & database :

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./service_account.json");

var defaultApp = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "http://myAdress.firebase"
});

var db = admin.database()

performWork()

function performWork() {

    var arg = process.argv[2]
    var ref = db.ref("something");
    ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
      console.log(arg);
      process.exit(1); 
    });

}
```

I'm going to launch a process every minute, so I what I want to do is to give to my child the firebase database as argument, so I do not create an access to firebase each time I launch a process.
So this is what I tried to do in index.js:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./service_account.json");

var defaultApp = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "http://myAdress.firebase"
});

var db = admin.database()
```

...

```
function launchWorker(path) {
    const worker = child_process.spawn('node', ['./worker.js', path.substring(1), admin.database()])
```

I simply pass the database as an argument to my worker. 
Then on my worker I get the fb :

```
function performWork() {

    var arg = process.argv[2]
    var db = process.argv[3]
    var ref = db.ref("something");
    ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
      console.log(arg);
      process.exit(1); 
    });

}
```

But when I reached an url I get an error :

```
TypeError: db.ref is not a function
    at performWork (/home/user/worker.js:12:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/worker.js:6:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

I think that worker.js does not know firebase at all, and cannot reach the function .ref. even if db is not null (I can print its value) 
So my question is what I need to import / do in the worker.js so it can execute code from firebase module ? I tries to user require... but nothin is working. 
My question is also more general, I would like to write some helpers (create, read, delete) in another file, but I will get the same problem. 
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Why do you think it is necessary to use child processes?  I don't see anything that would suggest they're necessary, and using child processes comes with non-negligible performance penalties.

Comment: I need to use child process to free memory, it is heavy task called more than frequently, this is the only way I found to really free memory when processes are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass a live Javascript object to another process.  If the object contains ONLY Javascript data, you can serialize it with JSON and pass it to the other process where a copy will be deserialized, but that won't work for an object that has native code or a TCP connection behind it which is likely what your open database handle represents.  There are some circumstances where you can pass a TCP connection to another process (clustering does that), but if you have it wrapped in another connection object (which it usually is), then it's a bunch of work to reconstitute a live connection object with the passed TCP connection in it in another process.  Personally, I'd rather avoid all that hassle.

Unless you have heavy CPU work going on in your child process, I don't really see any reason to need a child process here.  You can just do whatever database work you want to in the main process when the request comes in.  Database work should be mostly asynchronous and thus should not block the main node.js thread appreciably and you should be able to have multiple requests in flight at the same time.  With lots of requests, your database will be the bottleneck anyway, not the main node.js process.

If you have a legitimate reason to use child processes and you don't want to open and close a new DB connection for each one, then you probably want to create a bunch of worker processes that you open and they stay open. Then, they can open their own connection to the database and keep it open.  When a new request arrives in your main node.js process, you use some form of IPC (perhaps just writing to stdin of the child process) to send it a new job which it is just sitting there waiting to process.  You can optimize things by deciding how many working processes you should have to optimize the throughput.  Then, when a new job comes in, you just drop the job into a queue.  If there are any free workers, you send the next job in the queue to that worker.  Each time a worker finishes a job, you check to see if there's another item in the queue to send that worker.

Doing it this way, you aren't creating and killing new connections to your database all the time and each worker process can just have and keep its own database connection.

Comment: Well, thank you for the explanation, yes I have a huge number of process to run (once every 30 second, once every minutes, once every 5, once every 10...) dealing with a lot of data, I have 16 gb ram, it is the only way I found to free memory, when the child process ends, everything is release, my server can run this process for month without rebooting because of an out of memory error. Thanks.